# T6 Kombi T30 Startline 150ps 2l Tdi - Stock Wheel Size

Tags: vw, wheels

I'm having a hard time working out what my options are for new wheels for my T6.

I'm not sure of the width of the basic stock wheels that came with the (startline) van. I've linked pictures with tyre spec, but not sure if that clarifies anything regarding the wheels.

The tyre size reads 205/65R16C

I know I want some wheels and tyres that are load rated correctly for the van (T30), I'd like them matte black, and something bigger than 16's, with a decent width that doesn't extend past the wheel arches.

So my questions are, what is the width and offset of the current stock wheels that I have?

What other features or specifics do I need to look for when choosing new wheels to fit?

Thanks in advance

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi @gb2d, welcome to the site. Shopping questions are off-topic here as they're too localised and go stale quickly, so I've edited the question slightly to keep it on-topic and focus on how you can work out which wheels will fit.

Comment: Thank you for editing and not closing, that's appreciated.

Comment: No problem - I'd always rather edit than close where possible - it isn't always possible however!

Answer (score 1):

VW vans are bolt pattern 5x120, offset 50-55 ideally.

It seems that the lowest load rating for this van is 103, both based on research and based on your picture.

The current rims will be 6.5J as that's the VW spec for a 205 width tyre.